# Processing a long running process (uploading large Excel files); Ruby on Rails 4.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel

I have a create action in a controller that is in charged of uploading Excel files. Some of these Excel files take a long time to process. Once the Excel file is validated and the content of the file is saved in a table, the user is redirected to another view where they see a success flash notification.

I would like to alter this process but honest to gosh I would love some guidance or perhaps a link to something similar.

1) I am trying to make it so, once the create button is selected and the validations pass, the user is redirected elsewhere and once the file upload is completed, the user will be notified regardless on where they are in the application.

2)While an excel file is being processed, the create option is not available to any other user. (Currently, if the file is being processed, it stays in the new view and if you keep clicking on the create button, it processes the file over again prolonging the uploading process)

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: you can used `delayed_job` for processing your file n once you delayed job is enqueue in active record you can get the job id of given job and once your delayed  job is complete you can you show notification to user. For details of how to show progress of your delayed_job you can check gem `progress_job`

Answer (score 0):

From my point of view you should do following steps:

1) Create a special storage for states (global place where information about file upload status is stored). I propose to use key-value storage such as `redis` or `memcached`

2) When user upload file you save it to the disk, queue background job (`resque` or `delayed_job`) and set flag `file_is_processing` to true

3) In your views disable button if `file_is_processing` flag is set.

4) In background job you validate file and if it is not valid set a flag in storage `not_valid_file` & remove `file_is_processing` flag

5) Have before action where you check this state and if file is not valid redirect user to file upload page with notice & remove `not_valid_file` flag.

6) If file is valid you parse file then remove `file_is_processing` flag & set `file_is_processed`

7) In before action redirect user to success page, show notice & remove `file_is_processed`

Seems to be easiest way for me.